# Difference between 2d and 3d line in opengl

Tags: opengl, 3d, 2d

I am trying to use z coordinate as the depth so that when I draw two objects one can appear behind the other one. I tried drawing line using 3 coordinates but it failed, and I get different lines when compared to drawing of 2 coordinated lines(I put z coordinate to 0.0f

```
 GLfloat crossLine[] = {

        -1.0f, 0.2f,  // Vertex 1 (X, Y)
         0.0f, 0.2f,  // Vertex 2 (X, Y)

    };
```

and

```
 GLfloat crossLine[] = {

        -1.0f, 0.2f, 0.0f, // Vertex 1 (X, Y, Z)
         0.0f, 0.2f, 0.0f // Vertex 2 (X, Y, Z) 
    };
```

This is the snapshot: http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/78/thwc.png

Here is the code:

```
void myWidget::initialize()
{
    m_program = new QOpenGLShaderProgram(this);
    m_program->addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Vertex, vertexShaderSource);
    m_program->addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Fragment, fragmentShaderSource);
    m_program->link();
    m_posAttr = m_program->attributeLocation("posAttr");
    m_mycolor = m_program->uniformLocation("mycolor");
    m_source = m_program->uniformLocation("sourcePoint");
    m_matrixUniform = m_program->uniformLocation("matrix");

    glViewport(0, 0, width(), height());

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    m_program->bind();

    QMatrix4x4 matrix;
    matrix.perspective(60, 4.0/3.0, 0.1, 100.0);
    matrix.translate(0, 0, -2);
    matrix.rotate(100.0f * m_frame / screen()->refreshRate(), 0, 1, 0);

    m_program->setUniformValue(m_matrixUniform, matrix);


    glClearDepth(1.0);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc( GL_LEQUAL );
    glEnable(GL_COLOR);

}

void myWidget::drawLine(GLfloat vertices[], GLint verticesNumber, GLfloat color[], GLfloat z)
{


    glUniform4fv(m_mycolor, 1, color);
    glVertexAttribPointer(m_posAttr, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDrawArrays( GL_LINE_STRIP , 0, verticesNumber);
}
```

Comment: What does your drawing code look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get different lines when compared to drawing of 2 coordinated lines

```
glVertexAttribPointer(m_posAttr, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);
                                 ^ whaaaat?
```

In your "3D" case you're telling OpenGL that your line coordinates are these:

```
( -1.0f, 0.2f )
( 0.0f, 0.0f )
```

Try changing that `2` to a `3` in your `glVertexAttribPointer()` call.

Comment: This was very helpful genpfault. Thanks a lot. Is it possible to send coordinate z that is the same for all vertices only once?